# Google spreadsheet Multiple result with VLOOK UP

Tags: google-sheets

The VLOOKUP formulas which works individually are

```
=if(VLOOKUP(E2,DB!$C:$E,1,0)>0,"COMPLETED",)
=if(VLOOKUP(E2,DB!$F:$H,1,0)>0,"IN PROGRESS",)
```

The issue is while displaying both results in a single cell, the formula which I came up for this was

```
C2=if(AND(VLOOKUP(E4,DB!$C:$E,1,0)>0),"COMPLETED",if(VLOOKUP(E4,DB!$F:$H,1,0)>0,"IN PROGRESS","UNDEFINED"))
```

I have tested the formula with normal conditions other than VLOOKUP and it works without any issues, not sure what's wrong with it.

```
Example : C10=if(AND(E10=1),"ONE",if(E10=2,"TWO","NO DATA"))
```

Any help appreciated. 
May be its something simple but I am pulling my hair out for the last 3 hours.

Thanks :)
/*-----------------------*/

Updated 03.05.2016

Sorry for the comments that I have posted as I am new at using Stack overflow.

I have tried with only IF statements without any AND conditions, but the result is still same. The VLOOKUP is not returning the second value.

```
 C15=IF(VLOOKUP(E15,DB!$F:$H,1,0)>0,"COMPLETED",if(VLOOKUP(E15,DB!$F:$H,1,0)>0,"IN PROGRESS","UNDEFINED"))
```

> What I am expecting in cell C2 (sheet1) is check the values in cell
>   E2 against the columns C:H ( Sheet 2/ DB).  If it belongs to
>   Column C:C in (sheet2/DB) then the value in C2 (sheet1) should display
>   as "Completed" else if the value is in column F:F ( sheet2/DB) then in C2
>   (sheet1) should display "In Progress".

Link to my spreadsheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XYCUU_GCzTLETRkBtjJZrvyiRVcbNWb6Kpy4QRgNono/edit#gid=408015554)

Comment: VLOOKUP throws N/A if the value isn't found. You can use `if(isna(vlookup(...)), "something", "something else")` to handle this.

Comment: I also don't understand why you are using `and` with one boolean argument.

Comment: Your data structure is not clear. Vlookup is not being used correctly. AND() is not being used in any way that makes sense. Vlookup looks in the ***first*** column of a range only. Your formula does not look in range C to E. At all. Instead of getting lost in wrong formulas, please edit your question, provide a data sample, provide the desired result and the logic that leads to that. Again, edit the question. Don't put that into a comment. Post a comment after you've added more detail to notify people who are following the question.

Comment: The tags [tag:excel-formula], [tag:vlookup] and [tag:conditional-formatting] are related to Excel, not to Google Sheets and neither to spreadsheets apps in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your formula.

1. `VLOOKUP` and similar functions search within a single row or column, and it seems like you're looking for your value in multiple rows and columns.
2. As @Meta mentioned, `VLOOKUP` returns `N/A` when the value is not found in the range, and you are expecting a *zero or less* value to be returned (when you check for `>0` in the `IF` statement). Note that `VLOOKUP` returns the cell value itself and not an index of a match (like the `MATCH` function).

My suggestion is to replace your `VLOOKUP`s with `COUNTIF`.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(DB!$F:$H,E2)>0,"COMPLETED",IF(COUNTIF(DB!$C:$D,E2)>0,"IN PROGRESS","UNDEFINED"))
```

`COUNTIF` counts in multiple rows and columns, and will return a zero if no matches are found.

Comment: Thanks heaps I was thinking N/A should be only if both values cannot be found in the table.